# How to get complex return value which are include vector tuple in C# from C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++

I am making a c++ DLL to export C#.
Now I faced complex problem to get vector<tuple<int, vector, int, double, cv::Rect>> from C++ dll to C# application.

the return value like a blow.

```
class       : 1
points      : [92, 0;
 94, 2;
 98, 0]
area        : 17
probability : 0.600231
Rect        : [7 x 3 from (92, 0)]
```

Addition description:

Originally I made C++ API and use it in C++.
Then now I would like to export c++ DLL to c#.
So, I make the wrapper classes to use in C#.

This is the C++ function.

```
vector<tuple<int, vector<Point>, int, double, cv::Rect>> func(double v1, double v2, int v3, Rect roi = Rect());
```

The second vector is not the fixed size.
So I think I couldn't make them be a class.

```
void vecMat(MyCls * c, int idx, cv::Mat *&res, int& img_count, int& mat_type_size)
{
    mat_type_size = sizeof(cv::Mat);
    img_count = c->result[idx].img.size();
    res = new cv::Mat[img_count];

    for (int i = 0; i < img_count; i++)
    {
        cv::Mat& A = res[i];
        A = c->result[idx].img[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your current approach to this problem? As you have said, C++/C# interoperability is complex problem, so you should try to read about it, then split into few smaller problems and search for solutions for these. Right now the question is quite broad.

Comment: For now I vote for closing the question with need for clarity, since there many details missing, (like do you want to modify this vector on C# side, what do you mean by "return" a vector) that indicate lack of the research. (PS. I'd start with googling "C++/C# interoperability")

Comment: Create a structure(s) that are the same size in both c++ and C#.  Do you always have two points.  If not then points should point to a seconds structure with the actual points.  Then the main structure should also have a length property of the number of points.

Comment: @R2RT I'm not sure my additional description is fine. Then I search interoperability. I've got some of them. But I didn't clear yet for my problem.